# catch exception in managed bean and show message on screen in jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, exception

I'm using JSF 2 and I'm getting some exception while I'm using some web service and I want to catch that exception and display the message on my `.xhtml` page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the `try-catch` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) to catch and handle the exception. You can use [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29) to add a faces message to the faces context. You can use [`<h:messages>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/messages.html) to display faces messages.

So, something like this in the bean:

```
try {
    data = yourWebService.retrieve();
} catch (YourWebServiceException e) {
    String message = "Failed to retrieve data from webservice: " + e.getMessage());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, null));
    e.printStackTrace(); // Or use a logger.
}
```

And this in the JSF page:

```html
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

*(the `globalOnly="true"` will force the `<h:messages>` to only show messages with a `null` client ID)*

Comment: Its not working for me or may be im doing something wrong. I have a method where im passing URL and thats a asynchronous call so i dont get any response back. But when im sending the wrong URL then its throwing the WebApplicationException. And im not sure either im using that <h:messages /> tab properly or not. Im trying to use that in where my tabview is started. Please let me know is there anything im doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: It'd be helpful if you show an SSCCE. There's too much ambiguity here. If you use JSF the right way, then it'd just be matter of referencing the messages component in the `<f:ajax render>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example to what BalusC has explained, you could write a simple method that gets called in a catch statement.

```
private void addErrorMessage(String msg, String clientId) {
        String codingErrorMsgKey = "coding_error_msg";
        FacesMessage fm;
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
            ResourceBundle bundle = facesContext.getApplication().getResourceBundle(facesContext, "bundle");
            fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, bundle.getString(codingErrorMsgKey), bundle.getString(codingErrorMsgKey));
        }
        else {
            fm = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
        }
        facesContext.addMessage(clientId, fm);
    }
```

What the method does is really simple : you give it a message that you may have resolved earlier form your application's resource bundle, then a global (only if clientId is null) error (because of `FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR`) `FacesMessage` is created. The created error message is then added to the `facesContext` using a default string as the message if you didn't provide any.

Since this method is able to create global and clientId-related error messages, you won't have to use `globalOnly` property. Simply specify `<h:messages/>` to have the tag display all of your messages (global or not).

Again, this only is sample code. You may have to adjust/improve to make it your own. Also, you could almost duplicate this method to handle information messages.

As a generic way of dealing with error messages, you could make this method available in a super class that every controller would then extend.