# How shall technical exceptions be handled when invoked through a listener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using a `<h:selectOneMenu>` with an valueChangeListener attribute attached to it. The listener invokes some business code (eg. DB query) to load additional data based on the new selected value. I noticed that when an (unexpected) exception happens in that code, a `AbortProcessingException` wraps the original exception, which is followed by a log but without notifying the user that something went wrong.

Is there a way to notify the user that something unexpected went fatally wrong when invoking a listener ?

I know from [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382) that an action would be more appropriate for such an expression, however I cannot set an action in `<h:selectOneMenu>`, but only a listener. How shall I change my page so that a "real business action" (one that is allowed to fail) gets invoked when the selected item changes ?

Answer (score 0):

JSF has a concept of FacesMessages. These are rendered with the help of the `<h:messages />` tag. What is often done, is to catch any Exceptions and add a `javax.faces.application.FacesMessage` to the FacesContext, giving the user informations he needs (see also ["catch exception in managed bean and show message on screen in jsf2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297328)).

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    null, 
    new FacesMessage(Severity.INFO, <see details for possible fills>)
);
```

There are also the way to introduce an own `ExceptionHandlerFactory` - like mentioned in the article ["Global handling of all unchecked / unexpected exceptions in JSF 2"](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.ie/2010/10/global-handling-of-all-unchecked.html)- have you checked this possibility? (see also [this answer/comment to BalcusCs article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483339/1269441) )

As possibility two, you can e.g. use an ajax-request after the `selectOneMenu` got changed and trigger another Listener with that (it is executed later then the `ValueChangedListener` and gives the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` as parameter, what I find to be more helpful on BL - side). Here is some meta-code ...

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
  <f:selectItems ... />
  <f:ajax render="..." execute="..." listener="..." />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I do not want to wrap each listener within `try {...} catch (Exception) {addMessage("error");}`. I would expect the same behaviour as a plain action : any fatal/unexpected exception is only caught by the web-server and an error page is displayed.

Comment: Further, solution 2 still invokes a listener, and JSF will swallow any exception that is raised by the listener.

Comment: Always happy to help you achieving your goals. That's right, a listener usually swallows the exceptions, so solution 1 helps you catch it and send an individual message to the user via FacesMessages. If you want a "one-size-fits-all"-solution, investigate the `ExceptionHandlerFactory` solution. You are also right, that the f:ajax-listener is "just another listener", but because it is executed in an other part of the lifecycle, it might give you additional possibilities, e.g. forwarding/redirecting. It's your project, your decisions.